# cannot resolved method getChildFragmentManager()

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-studio-2.2

error: The 'childFragmentManager' parameter only can be used if the getChildFragmentManager() method is available in android.support.v4.app.Fragment, update your support library version.

i have  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0' in my gradle. My code like;

```
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import org.androidannotations.annotations.*;
 import org.androidannotations.annotations.sharedpreferences.Pref;
.
.

@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_main)
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
@Pref
ApplicationSettings_ applicationSettings;
@ViewById(R.id.bot)
public LinearLayout bot;
@ViewById(R.id.center)
public LinearLayout center;
@Bean
UIItemGenerator uiItemGenerator;
@SystemService
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
@FragmentById(value = R.id.contentFragment,childFragment = true)
public ContentFragment contentFragment;

public MainFragment() {
}

@Click(R.id.imagebutton_ribbon)
public void ribbonClick(View view) {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

.
.
.
@AfterViews
public void afterViews() {
    if (contentFragment == null)
        contentFragment = (ContentFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contentFragment);
    for (int j = 0; j < bot.getChildCount(); j++) {
        bot.getChildAt(j).setSelected(false);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < top.getChildCount(); j++) {
        top.getChildAt(j).setSelected(false);
    }
    ll_home.setSelected(true);
    ll_allrooms.setSelected(true);
    initUI();
    contentFragment.generateContent(-1, -1);
    imagebutton_top_rightarrow.setSelected(true);
    imagebutton_bot_rightarrow.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

getChildFragmentManager() is a method on Fragment and check your import statement

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

I think you are using AppCompatActivity(child class of FragmentActivity), you have to use this

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Comment: He extends Fragment not Fragment Activity, please check the question carefully before posting your answer.